# Changing default phone for Google login device

Tags: ios

So the following annoying thing happened to me. I wanted to print some documents at my local printer shop from my Google Drive.

However, Google decided I can't log in because it doesn't recognize my device. It wanted me to go to my phone and get a security code.

However, I didn't have the phone Google thought to be my default phone (Android device) and didn't allow me to choose my other phone, which I actually use (an iPhone).

Just like that, I was locked out of my own account, unable to print anything. So my question is:

Where can I change my default phone so it sends a push confirmation to my iPhone when I log in from an unknown device instead of the Android?

Answer (score 2):

Go to [myaccount.google.com](https://myaccount.google.com/), sign in and click on `Sign in and Security`.

Scroll down and go to `Account Recovery Options` and click on `Recovery Phone`

Add/remove the phone numbers according to your preferences.

Then go back, scroll down and click on `Recently Used devices` and remove all the devices that are not in use. If your Iphone is not displayed here then make sure that you've `signed in` in your IPhone with `Google Account.`

Comment: I did not need a phone number on my Android, is it an option not to have a phone number added, and still being able to let myself in via the iPhone? I'd prefer not to give Google my phone number. Basically I want to get a push notification for logging in on my iPhone instead of the Android - is this possible?